# set cookie in onether file with `curl_setopt` etc

Tags: php, curl, setcookie

I'm googling trying to find a solution to my problem.

I need to set a cookie in a diferent file and i'm trying with `curl_setopt` but it doesnt work.

Any way the idea is send with PHP the value to set cookie in another page, something like this:

```
    file1.php

    <? //start php
    //at the begining of the file i have
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//if i set a cookie now it give me an error cause i can not change the header
//but because i need to set a cookie now without leaving this file
//i tryed to set it in file2.php this way:
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $SITE_HOME_DIR ."login.php");
// Do a POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email=pok@pok.com'); 
curl_close($ch);
    ///end php
    ?>

    file2.php
    <?
//just set cookie
setcookie("TestCookie", $_POST['email'], time()+3600)
?>
```

But this doesn'work....

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You need to explain your concept of "different file" or "other page". Cookies are set with [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) normally, not with [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl_setopt).

Comment: Still unclear what your actual goal is. What's the issue with just using `setcookie` in the first file? Explain how you expect this to behave, in which setting. (The edited code doesn't illustrate anything.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set a cookie for the next script with [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie). There is no other option. -- cURL sends distinct requests to other pages, but cannot possibly set any cookies at the client (browser).

Your error is explained in [Headers already sent (reference answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php). You may or may not have luck with the mentioned `ob_start()` workaround, if you can't/won't rewrite your page.

Comment: You are right...i'm sorry i didn't...but i read it now. And thank you. But the funny thing is that i tryed to setcookie after a session start and a header and it is working! I hope to continue to work well.